# Multi select Elements with Angular 2 / 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, select

Basically I want know how to do this with Angular 2/4 (Sorry is in Spanish).

[image]

- Using *NgFor I want to select 1 or more Items to enable an HTML
  Element and If none element is selected, I need to disable it to show
  the default element.
- I want to know how can I do something similar to this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8AUTzkbbuQPkf66kw6MZ?p=preview) and [this](http://nightlycoding.com/index.php/2014/02/click-and-drag-multi-selection-rectangle-with-javascript/) but with a Card List for example (the same effect holding Ctrl or Shif and dragging the mouse to select items and get the data).

I have something like this

```
<div class="col s3">
  <button *ngIf="add" mz-button float="true"><i mz-icon [icon]="'add'"></i></button>
  <button *ngIf="!add" mz-button float="true"><i mz-icon [icon]="'remove'"></i></button>
</div>

<mz-card *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios" (click)="onSelecPersona()">
    <mz-card-content>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">
          {{usuario.nombre}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 right-align">
          <i *ngIf="usuario.admin" mz-icon-mdi [icon]="'star'"></i>
          <i *ngIf="!usuario.admin" mz-icon-mdi [icon]="'star-2'"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mz-card-content>
  </mz-card>
```

and my component is

```
add = true;
  usuarios = [
    { nombre: 'Alexis Wursten', admin: false  },
    { nombre: 'Janco Boscan', admin: true  },
    { nombre: 'Noemi Iturralde', admin: false  },
  ];

  onSelecPersona() {
    this.add = false;
  }
```

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full example code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: `
            <mz-card [class.selected]="usuario.selected" *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios" (click)="onSelecPersona(usuario)" (mouseenter)="onMouseOver($event, usuario)" (mouseleave)="onMouseOver($event, usuario)">
                <mz-card-content>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s6">
                      {{usuario.nombre}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6 right-align">
                      <i *ngIf="usuario.admin" mz-icon-mdi [icon]="'star'"></i>
                      <i *ngIf="!usuario.admin" mz-icon-mdi [icon]="'star-2'"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </mz-card-content>
              </mz-card>
          `,
    styles: [`
            mz-card-content {
              user-select: none;
            }
            .selected {
              background: red;
            }
          `]
})
export class NameComponent {
    private dragStart:number = 0;
    private dragOver:number = 0;

    constructor() {}

    @HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
    onMouseDown(ev) {
        this.dragStart = ev.clientY;
    }
    @HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
    onMouseUp(ev) {
        this.dragStart = 0;
        this.dragOver = 0;
    }

    public usuarios:Array<{id?: number; nombre: string; admin: boolean;}> = [
        { nombre: 'Alexis Wursten', admin: false  },
        { nombre: 'Janco Boscan', admin: true  },
        { nombre: 'Noemi Iturralde', admin: false  },
    ];
    public added: string[] = [];

    onSelecPersona(item) {
        if(this.added.indexOf(item.nombre)===-1) { // or compare by id
            this.added = this.added.concat([item.nombre]);
        }
        else {
            this.added = this.added.filter((x) => item.nombre!==x); // or compare by id
        }
        this.usuarios = this.usuarios.map((x) => (x===item.nombre ? Object.assign({}, x, { selected: !(this.added.indexOf(item.nombre)!==-1) }) : x));
    }

    onMouseOver(ev, item) {
        if(ev.which!==1) {
            return false;
        }

        ev.preventDefault();

        if(ev.type==='mouseenter' && !item.selected) {
            this.dragOver = ev.clientY - this.dragStart > 0 ? 1:-1;
            this.onSelecPersona(item);
            return false;
        }

        if(ev.type==='mouseleave') {
            if(this.dragOver===1 && ev.clientY < ev.target.offsetTop && item.selected) {
                console.log('desel...', item);
                this.onSelecPersona(item);
                return false;
            }
            if(this.dragOver===-1 && ev.clientY > ev.target.offsetTop && item.selected) {
                console.log('desel...', item);
                this.onSelecPersona(item);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This helped me like 70% or 80% of what I need, with this I can finish the first point, now I need to search how to do the drag effect like the Plunker example.

Comment: Thats quite more complicated, I'll think about this and if I have something on my mind will Edit my answer ;].

Comment: You may try to do it with multi select box like in the example from plunker !?

Comment: Thanks, I need do it with cards element like in the img, do you know how can I change the background color of the selected items?

Comment: I have edited my answer I hope that will help you for what you are looking for like behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me alot, I found an Angular JS Lib that is exactly what Im looking for ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-multiple-selection ), now I need to see how to implement it xD

Comment: OK, I wanted just to let you know. That in the example I provide you, you can select elements while holding the left mouse button and drag over the elements ;]

Comment: Thanks, you are the best, I hope I can be like you xD. I checked your example and is excelent I can use it and search how to draw a rectangle that is what is missing to finish, but is the same function with and "invisible" rectangle.